# Я хотел написать, а точнее повторить простую програму из ютуба. Написал всё как на видио, но програма не работает

Tags: python-3.x, linux, виртуальная-машина

Думаю,проблема заключается в том что я програмирую на chromebook 11a g6,используя при этом среду разработки Linux (Debian 10 (Buster))
Вот видео с той программой:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gon0MvppfF8

```
import eel

eel.init("veb")

eel.start("main.html", size=(700, 700))
```

Это файл main.py

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Weather</title>

<script src="eel.js"></script>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Привет, мир!</h1>




</body>
</html>
```

Это файл main.html
[image]
[image: Вот как оно выгледит в файлах]

[image: Вот что оно мне пишет при зпуске]

Answer (score 0):

Для работы eel нужно установить браузер хром или хромиум.

Comment: так у меня и так есть хром

Comment: значит установлен не правильно.